# ASP.NET Core validation razor markup

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to output some basic validation--say, "is required"--using razor syntax without data annotations on my model.

Typical code might look like this:

```
<span asp-validation-for="MyModel.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
```

But the examples I've seen require data annotations, like

```
[Required]
```

How can I output html validation without the data annotations?

Comment: Is there any reason you did not want to `data annotations`? If you insist on this requirement, you will need javascript form validation, you could refer [JavaScript Form Validation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) to implement validation by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

place the required tag in the input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="@MyModel.Name" required >
<span asp-validation-for="@MyModel.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Comment: What about MinLength, Range, etc.?

Comment: just use MinLength and Min and Max for the range in the input